# Webgl on nexus 5

Tags: android, webgl

I have developed some webGL code in html file and tested the same on desktop browsers. Its working fine. Now i would like to test it on nexus 5 smartphone. How to test my own webGL code on android running smartphones? Does Nexus 5 support webGL?

Comment: open browser and test it?

Comment: Well i do not own nexus now. If some one out there has already tested this i would like to know if it works. Thanks!

Comment: My website loads one or two models, but the third ones crashes. I am not sure if this is an issue with a lack of support for WebGL on the Nexus5X or a graphics / memory issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As this question is not closed, http://get.webgl.org tells me that my nexus 5 supports webgl.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried some WEB functionalities on my nexus 5, you can create a local server and access it over a wifi network or try some experiments at google experimets some of the uses webgl and other uses CSS3D, some of them have worked but very slow and other smooth